# Xamarin iOS Private API Use

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsurlrequest, iphone-privateapi

I would like to implement an iOS private API in my `Xamarin` project.

Can someone explain, how I can implement the following private API in Xamarin?

I think I need to create a binding project, but I cannot get it to work.

The following code works when running in my native iOS project.

**My .h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSURLRequest (IgnoreSSL)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host;

@end
```

---

**My .m file:**

```
#import "NSURLRequest+IgnoreSSL.h"

@interface NSURLRequest ()
@end

@implementation NSURLRequest (IgnoreSSL)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host
{
    // ignore certificate errors only for this domain
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: You probably already know this but (for the benefit of everyone reading the question) Apple **will** reject application that uses **private** API if they are submitted to the AppStore. If you use such tricks when developing make sure to disable them before submitting!

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is create a small library in Objective-C that only does what you are doing there (overriding a static method in NSURLRequest) and link it with your application.

Alternatively, if you want to do this with pure C#, you could try creating a subclass of NSUrlRequest, and then adding code like this:

```
class MyUrlRequest : NSUrlRequest {
    // Provide any constructors that you need

    [Export ("allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:")]
    static bool Allow (string host) { return true; }
}
```

Then create instances of MyUrlRequest instead of NSUrlRequest.

Comment: No knowledge of mono, but can't C# class extensions be used (much like Objective C extensions)? It is not always possible to use a private subclass of URL requests, and there are mutable versions to consider.

Comment: ObjC categories and C# extensions methods are somewhat similar. However C# extensions methods can **extend** but not replace existing .NET code. To do the former (ObjC) behaviour you'll need to do **method swizzling** (swap two methods bodies at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity have you tried if using:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

Would do the trick?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, c, e) => true;
```

Comment: This will **only** work when using .NET (BCL) types for doing HTTPS, e.g. `WebRequest`, `WebClient`, `HttpClient` (at least for the default managed provider), `SslStream` and the types that uses them (e.g. the web service stack). IOW it won't work for bindings like `NSUrlRequest` and the like (in `monotouch.dll`).